# Replace each word in a string with (the first letter + number of characters between + last letter)

Tags: objective-c, string, parsing, append

I'm using objective-c to parse a sentence here:

```
NSString *myString = @“Some words to form a string”;
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
NSMutableString *firstCharacters = [NSMutableString string];
NSMutableString *lastCharacters = [myString substringFromIndex:[myString length] - 1]

NSArray *arrayOfWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
for (NSString *word in arrayOfWords) {
    if ([word length] > 0) {
        NSString *firstLetter = [word substringToIndex:1];
        [firstCharacters appendString:lastCharacters];
```

and then I am really stumped at this point. I want to NSLog the recombined string so that it looks like this:
"S2e w3s to f2m a s3g"

Comment: "S2e w3s to f2m a s4g"?

Comment: Once you have a NSArray filled, you can use the reverse method of `componentsSeparatedByString:`: `componentsJoinedByString:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code :

```
NSString *myString = @"Some words to form a string";

NSArray *wordsInSentence = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSMutableArray *expectedResultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *word in wordsInSentence) {

    NSString *finalExpectedString = word;

    if (word.length > 2) {

        NSString *firstLetterInWord = [word substringToIndex:1];

        NSString *lastLetterInWord = [word substringFromIndex:[word length] - 1];

        finalExpectedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d%@", firstLetterInWord, (int)word.length - 2, lastLetterInWord];

    }

    [expectedResultArray addObject:finalExpectedString];

}

NSString *printString = [expectedResultArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

NSLog(@"Result : %@", printString);
```